# C++ inline functions and redeclarations

Tags: c++, inline, declaration, redeclaration

First of all, sorry for my English.

Since GCC totally ignores inline specifiers, it's a little difficult for me to know when a funcion has been marked inline by me or not. What I'm trying to understand is, when you have some redeclarations of a same function (in a same translation unit or in different ones), when or under which circunstances your function is marked inline or not (irrespective of what will the compiler make with your hint).

For example:

```
inline void print();

void print();
```

or:

```
void print();
inline print();
```

What is the meaning of redeclaring a function with different inline specifiers?  A more complex example:

```
#include <iostream>

void print();

int main()
{
    print(); // (1)
}

inline void print() { std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl; }
```

From the exclusive point of view of C++ and not from the point of view of a compiler, is the `print` function an inline one at line `(1)`?

I cannot formulate my question conciselly, but I think the message has been received :) I'm trying to understand when a function is supposed to be marked inline and when not from the point of view of C++ and the programmer's (irrespective of what will the compiler make with your function).

Comment: "Since GCC totally ignores inline specifiers", that's news to me. On the contrary, as I recall g++ leans the other way, taking `inline` very literally as a command to inline calls.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-functions.html

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf GCC uses some heuristics based on function size to decide if a function will be inline or not, irrespective of your desires. For example, GCC does NEVER inline functions unless you specify the option -O2 or -O3. Even more, given -O2 and -O3 options, GCC will ignore an inline specifier if the function is specially big, and also mark a non-inline function as inline if the function is small. So, your hints, in general, doesn't count.

Answer (score 1):

`inline` allows an external linkage function to be defined (essentially identically) in two or more translation units.

which means defining it in a header.

when a function is `inline` it must be defined, and `inline`, and essentially <sup><sup>1)</sup></sup>identically, in every translation unit where it's used.

---

`inline` just accumulates. a function can't become un-`inline`.

---

in addition to these considerations `inline` serves as an optimization *hint*, that the compiler may freely ignore. in that capacity it states that you would like the machine code calls to this function to be inlined. generally the compiler can do a better job of deciding where that's a good idea or not.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> C++17 10.1.6/5 (dcl.inline/5): “An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case”</sup>

Comment: Ok, that means, with only one declaration/definition which is marked inline, every reference to the same function is treated as an inline function, with no further considerations, right?

Comment: And additionally, if a same function is marked inline in one translation unit, and in other translation unit isn't marked inline, the behaviour is undefined? or that does only happen when their definitions are differents in different translation units?

Comment: @Peregring-lk yes, and yes, and no, not only then

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "inline just accumulates. a function can't become un-inline." Could you please specify where in the standard can one deduce that from? Thank you.

Comment: @user42768: You can deduce that from two facts: (1) that an extern linkage `f` that is `inline` in one translation unit, must be `inline` in all translation units where it's used, and (2) that there is no syntax for un-`inline`-ing. Point (1) is an explicit requirement in the standard. Point (2) follows from reading the whole standard -- we're talking about an absence here, and you can't pinpoint that *within* the standard, except possibly narrowing it down to clauses about `inline`, if that feels good enough (note: sometimes it isn't).

Comment: I added a C++17 reference for (1) in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If there were a way to un-inline a function then the first reason doesn't really apply, because if I inline it and un-inline it in the same translation unit then it wouldn't count as an inline function anymore. The second reason, although unsatisfying, is the one that I would consider.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence:

> Since GCC totally ignores inline specifiers, it's a little difficult
>   for me to know when a function has been marked inline by me or not.

is an incorrect basis to start with. (And of course, we can replace GCC with any other modern compiler for this discussion).

Sure, the compiler may ignore the `inline` keyword for the purposes of deciding whether the function is inlined or not - and it CERTAINLY can inline functions that are NOT marked inline. The compiler does, however, use the `inline` keyword [and it's equivalence of "body declared inside the struct"] when generating the final output, to avoid multiple definitions of a function that has code generated multiple times in different compile units. For example:

```
 foo.h:
    inline int foo() { return 42; }

 a.cpp:
    #include "foo.h"

    ...

 b.cpp:
    #include "foo.h"

    ...
```

If the function `foo` was not declared `inline`, the linker would complain about multiple definitions of the function `foo` if we link the results of a.cpp and b.cpp into one executable file.

However, you are right in that the compiler will not decide to inline functions on the basis of the `inline` keyword, but based on other aspects, such as how many times the function is called, whether the source of the function is "visible" to the compiler, etc.

As a simple rule:

1. Compiler will **not** inline functions that it hasn't got the source code for.
2. Compiler will **not** inline virtual functions (unless it can determine the type of the object the virtual function belongs to)
3. The compiler **will** inline functions that are small and/or only called once, particularly if the function is static.

Since inlining happens towards the end of compilation (when ALL the source code have been parsed and placed in some sort of AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) or similar form), whether the function is before or after the point of usage typically doesn't really matter - of course, if the call is to a function that isn't part of the AST (the source code is not available), the compiler has no choice but to NOT inline it.

The exception to "can't inline when the source isn't available" is so called LTO "Link Time Optimisation". A traditional linker will just take a collection of machine code instructions and paste them together in whatever order they are listed, without any knowledge of what a function is [simplified view, sufficient for this discussion] and then fix up any addresses for functions and variable that the compiler couldn't resolve directly. In contrast, LTO stores the "object files" as an intermediate representation, and the final machine code generation is done by the linker phase. This means that the linker has enough information to for example move code around to inline the code in one function into another. This technology is available in recent releases of for example gcc (4.9.0 has LTO as a full feature, earlier versions had a bit less support)