# C++ inline redeclaration

Tags: c++, inline, redeclaration

Consider the following example (in the same translation unit):

```
inline void f();
void f() {}
```

What happens at the redeclaration of `f`? Is `f` still considered `inline`?

I looked in the standard for this situation but I only found the reverse of it in 10.1.6/6 [dcl.inline]:

> [...] If the definition of a function or variable appears in a translation unit before its first declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed. [...]

I would like some references in the standard which specify what happens in this situation.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595664/c-inline-functions-and-redeclarations), but it doesn't show an explicit reference in the standard. I'm inclined to believe there is no such reference.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Comment: This example occurs on page 158 of N4659

Comment: @M.M I read that example, but it doesn't say anything about whether the function is still `inline` or not, it only specifies the final linkage.

Comment: the only meaning of `inline` is the linkage

Comment: But a function declaration without `inline` and one with `inline` (both without any linkage specifiers) have the same linkage: `extern`.

Comment: `extern` is a keyword, not a linkage

Comment: I'm sorry, the correct term I believe is `external linkage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens at the redeclaration of `f`? Is `f` still considered `inline`?

Yes, `f` is still considered `inline`.

The relevant sections of the standard pertaining to the semantics of the `inline` function specifier can be found in [[dcl.fct.spec]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.spec#dcl.fct.spec):

> A function declaration ... with an `inline` specifier declares an inline function. The `inline` specifier indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism.
>
> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case ([basic.def.odr]). [ *Note*: A call to the inline function may be encountered before its definition appears in the translation unit.  — *end note* ] If the definition of a function appears in a translation unit before its first declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed. If a function with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required. An `inline` function with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units.

And in [[basic.def.odr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.def.odr#3):

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every *non-inline* function or variable that is odr-used in that program

Also see an example in [[dcl.stc]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.spec#dcl.stc-8):

> ```
> void h();
> inline void h();                // external linkage
>
> inline void l();
> void l();                       // external linkage
> ```

The interpretation of all that is:

- `inline` as a function specifier acts as a flag, expressing your wish to have the call to the given function inlined. Once it is encountered on a certain function declaration, it remains "set" for that specific function overload, and there is no way to "unset" it.
- It doesn't matter if you specify `inline` on a *declaration* or a *definition* of a function, because a definition [is also](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def#2) a declaration and because multiple declarations are [allowed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def#1).
  However, the `inline` specifier must be encountered *before* or *with* the definition of the function and *before* it is odr-used (*odr-use* means the compiler needs to actually emit code that invokes the function, or needs its address for whatever reason).
- The `inline` specifier has [no effect](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.spec#footnote-90) on the linkage of the function, which remains external for non-static global functions. If an address of an `inline` function (that has external linkage) is taken, the compiler will emit an out-of-line definition for it, making sure the linker can fold multiple definitions if necessary (e.g. using a weak symbol). That way the address of the `inline` function in different TUs will be the same.
- Once a function is declared `inline` and has external linkage, it must be declared `inline` in all other translation units that odr-use it.
- You must provide the definition of the `inline` function in every translation unit that odr-uses it, and it must be exactly the same.

Comment: I agree with everything you said. However, take for example the following two declarations: `extern const int a; extern int a;`. Why doesn't the same apply here, why doesn't `const` act like a flag as well? I searched for how `const` behaves in the context of redeclarations, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: `const` is a [*cv-qualifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.type.qualifier), it's part of the [type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.type#1), and you can't redeclare the same variable with a different type. `inline` is a [*specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.spec#dcl.fct.spec), it's not part of the type, more a compiler hint, like `virtual`.

Comment: Ok, now this makes sense. I know that it seems obvious, but does the standard explicitly say that "you can't redeclare the same variable with a different type"? I know that it says that all names in the same scope must refer to the same entity. Is it the same? Thank you.

Comment: I looked more in the standard, but [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic#scope.declarative-4.1) is still the only thing I believe could mean that one cannot redeclare a variable with a different type. However, as mentioned in my other related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355073/c-standard-definition-of-conflicting-declarations) by @xskxzr, this redeclaration is valid: `extern int a[]; extern int a[10];`, while `int[]` and `int[10]` are different types (specified explicitly in the standard).

Comment: C++ tries to be generic on this, since functions can be overloaded, it simply states that variables cannot be overloaded, see [\[over\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over#1).

Answer (score 1):

The effect of a redeclaration is specified in [[basic.def]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def)

> A declaration may introduce one or more names into a translation unit or **redeclare** names introduced by previous declarations. *If so, the declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of these names.*[...]

So by redeclaring, one can add specifications to a name but not remove them.