# C++ standard definition of conflicting declarations

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration

Where does the standard define what a conflicting declaration is?

For example, if I have, at namespace scope, the following declarations:

```
extern const int a;
extern int a;
```

this would be an example of *conflicting declarations*.

Comment: Since your question is "where?", the answer is here: [\[basic.scope\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.scope)

Comment: @Oliv Ok, maybe my wording in the question was wrong. I read part of the section that you linked before asking this question, but I could not find anything explicit. Could you please quote the standard saying that redeclarations must agree on types or something similar? Thank you!

Comment: [basic.def](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def#1)/1 *A declaration may introduce one or more names into a translation unit or redeclare names introduced by previous declarations. If so, the declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of these names* You can specifies the interpretation and attribute by redeclaring, but you can not change what you have already specified. (here you are changing the type)

Comment: But why can't I interpret the following: "*If so, the declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of these names*" as saying that the re-declaration "specifies the interpretation and attributes" of the name without taking into account the initial declaration, that is, like starting from empty "interpretation and attributes"?

Comment: So look at [basic.scope.declarative](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.declarative#4). But to understand it well you should read [basic.scope] entirely.

Comment: Reading this: "[...] they shall all refer to the same entity, [...]" made me think a bit differently. Does the standard intend to say that an *entity* is defined (not in the C++ sense) once, with all specifiers, and if that name is used again in a re-declaration, the second name can only "make a reference" to the existing entity, which already has all its "specifiers" "defined"?

Comment: Some related notes that may be helpful: C has the concept of "compatible type", and explicitly says declarations referring to the same object shall have compatible types, but C++ does not. In addition, there exists some special cases where different types for declarations of the same entity are allowed. For example, `int[]` and `int[N]`.

Comment: @xskxzr This is helpful. Does the C++ standard say explicitly that this sort of redeclaration is allowed?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[dcl.type]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.dcl#dcl.type), the *cv-qualifier* `const` is part of the type, therefore `const int x;` and `int x;` constitute different declarations of the variable `x`.

Then we arrive at [[over]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over), which states that:

> When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the same scope, that name is said to be overloaded. By extension, two declarations in the same scope that declare the same name but with different types are called overloaded declarations. Only function and function template declarations can be overloaded; variable and type declarations cannot be overloaded.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been struggling to find something similar in the standard for the entire day, but I did not think to look for it in the "Overloading" section. However, the example in [basic.types](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.types#6) referred to by @xskxzr is a bit of a contradiction, isn't it?

Comment: So what are different declarations? For example, is `extern inline int a;` 
different from `extern int a;`?

Comment: I was told about the existence of another paragraph which also includes the exception regarding arrays with/without bound: [basic.link/11](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#11).